# How can I stop the cursor in Eclipse from jumping around automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse

Let's say I have a `String` and I want to remove every comma in the string. I want to use `theString.replace(",", "")` I start to type and the autocomplete comes up:

[image: .rep]

I hit enter and it completes the method name:

[image: replace(oldChar, newChar]

I type the first quote. All is well:

[image: replace(", newChar)]

Then I type the comma. However, Eclipse thinks that the comma I typed is to separate the parameters, and my cursor jumps to the second parameter:

[image: replace(", newChar)]

This interrupts my typing and I'm tired of it. Eclipse preferences are a maze, so how do I turn this off?

Comment: Eclipse is a coding IDE, not made for typing. :)

Comment: Go to `Window/Preferences/Java/Editor` and change the settings.

Comment: Change what? http://i.imgur.com/qOzXi5D.png

Comment: It looks like this is hard-coded, as I couldn't find anything in the preferences for Java > Content Assist. Additionally, a bug report was filed a long time ago stating that it is a bug if entering "," doesn't take you to the next parameter: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=154740

Comment: Go to `Window/Preferences/Java/Editor/Coding Assist/Advanced` and un-check the auto **Java proposals** settings.

Comment: You'll quickly learn that hitting escape will do what you need. Whenever I use auto-complete and need to enter a string I have the *hit escape now* reflex.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Eclipse doesn't understand when you're typing in a string that the `,` you hit doesn't mean *go to the next parameter*. This is something hard-coded into their parser.

[image: Refactor border]

<sup>Take a look after the `r` in `newChar`; that's the border you're looking for.</sup>

You'll want to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> when you auto-complete since you are in *refactoring mode* (notice the border around the parameters).

This is similar to when renaming a method or field using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - the border appears, indicating what you're doing is supposed to be *"smart"*.